# The collection $\beta = \lbrace (-a,a) : a > 0 \rbrace$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that the collection

$\beta = \lbrace (-a,a) : a > 0 \rbrace$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$

is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I almost finished the problem so I still can not find a way to show that R is an element of the collection. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Unless the "abuse of notation" $a=\infty$ is allowed, it is not.

Comment: Also how do you show $\emptyset \in \mathcal T$ ?

Comment: Oh yeah, it's true I have not found a way to prove that $\emptyset$ is an element of the collection, I'm starting to suspect that there is an error, in the problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Looks like an error in the problem. If this is for a class, I would still submit a solution that says "it is not, but.." and proves if you add $\mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$ to the collection, the result is a topology.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not for lacking R and emptyset;  it is a base for a topology for R.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{T} = \beta \cup \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ is a topology. Closedness under finite intersections is clear. And if $(-a_i, a_i)$ is a family of sets from $\beta$ (for unions we can forget about cases with $\emptyset$ of $\mathbb{R}$ in it), either $\sup_i a_i = +\infty$, in which case it's easy to verify that $\cup_i (-a_i, a_i) = \mathbb{R}$ or $\sup_i a_i = b \in \mathbb{R}$, and then it's also not very hard (using properties of the supremum) that $\cup_i (-a_i, a_i )= (-b, b) \in \beta$.